# How to properly apply regex using OR condtion?

Tags: regex

Im using Jenkins text finder plugin in order to mark a build as a failure if some condition is true. One of those strings has to be greater zero in order to mark the build as fail:

```
0 errors | 0 warnings | 0 notes
```

Im using:

```
^[1-9]+ *errors [|] [1-9]+ *warnings [|] [1-9]+ *notes$
```

where I expect that if numbers of errors, warnings or notes are between 1-9 a failure has to occur. However testing that rule only work if ALL are at least 1.

How can I manage the regex in order to match:

```
 1 errors | 0 warnings | 0 notes
```

that at least ONE of the strings has to be 1.

I tested that on:

https://regex101.com/

Comment: Perhaps, you do not need that long a regex here. Try just `\b[1-9]\s*(?:errors|warnings|notes)`

Comment: There may be a possibility of having more than 9 errors/warnings/notes in which case you can try this too: `[1-9]\d*\s*(?:errors|warnings|notes)` [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/Ywt2k8/2)

Comment: Or even `\b0*[1-9]\d*\s*(?:errors|warnings|notes)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you want to match a string if it contains an integer number that is more than 0 before any of the three strings: `errors`, `warnings` and `notes`.

Use

```
[1-9][0-9]*\s*(?:errors|warnings|notes)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YL6Emj/2).

NOTE: if the number can only be a single digit number, use `[1-9]\s*(?:errors|warnings|notes)`.

**Details**

- `[1-9]` - a `1` to `9` digit
- `[0-9]*` - any 0+ digits
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  -`(?:errors|warnings|notes)` - one of  the substring.

Comment: Side note: I find it *unlikely* that you'd want to mark a Jenkins build as a "failure" if there is a "note" (or possibly even a "warning"). I would suggest marking the build as "unstable" in such circumstances.